# Simplest way to remove first part of a string if it matches (from beginning) ? (using boost is ok)

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17

```
std::string str_a = "Hello World";
std::string str_b = "Hello ";
```

If string matches from beginning, remove it or return it in a new string with result, doesn't matter. Result should then be "World".

Whats the most stupid and simplest way to this with [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ? One liner is preferred. **Performance is **NOT** a concern.** `std` is preferred, but [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) is also an option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
   std::string a = "Hello World";
   std::string b = "Hello ";

   if (a.find(b) == 0)
   {
       std::cout << "\"" << a.substr(b.length()) << "\"\n";
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given `if performance is not a concern` this is a good answer. But it's not how I would do it myself as `find` will search all positions in the source string until it finds a match, not just the first.

Comment: Agreed, though it states exactly that ;-) However, if he's able to upgrade to C++20 he could use `std::string::starts_with` which should provide better performance.

Comment: @Cornholio boost has starts_with already, i could use that

Comment: If you're already using boost do that, though I wouldn't pull in a boost dependency for such a task. Check out @John's answer, it's a way better approach for checking if a string begins with another string than my `find` based solution ;-)

Comment: @Cornholio I think this one using find is more clear and performance is irrelevant - but with starts_with even more clear

Answer (score 3):

```
if (str_a.compare(0, str_b.size(), str_b) == 0)
    str_a = str_a.substr(str_b.size());
```

Seems straightforward and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best performance, but in one line:

```
std::string str_c = (str_a.find(str_b) == 0) ? str_a.substr(str_b.size()) : str_a;
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
if (str_a.compare(0, str_b.size(), str_b) == 0)
    str_a.erase(0, str_b.size());
```

Use `erase` to avoid constructing a temporary string